# How to launch View Controller from a custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller

I need to launch a `ViewController` from my custom `UICollectionViewCell` but i cant access my `navigationController` there so I don't know how to launch it because I know only one way.

Only like this for example

```
LoginViewController *loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:loginView animated:YES];
```

Any idea how can I do it ?

This is how I normally call `cell` click

```
- (void)collectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView didSelectCell:(PSCollectionViewCell *)cell atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
[NjoftimeManager setSelectedListing:[[NjoftimeManager getMainListings] objectAtIndex:index]];
ListingViewController *listingView = [[ListingViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:listingView animated:YES];
}
```

But what i want to do is call somethign different from here

```
- (void) profileTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
//some code

NSLog(@"PROFILI %li",(long)gesture.view.tag);
}
```

I have given a tag to the footer view of the `cell` and want to do something different when that is clicked and I can only get the tap event here in `Cell` class.

Comment: You need to your UINavigationController as a rootViewController in main window. then you can able to launch it.

Comment: If you are using story board, you can bind the collection view cell and new controller (and select push). so that on tapping the collection view cell, it will push new view controller. Or else explicity call "performSegueWithIdentifier". Will it solve your problem?

Comment: I dont use story board nor xib, only code

Comment: So if you are using only code, define block on the cell. Assign them to cell and call them on desired action. Or you can write your custom extension of ViewController adding navigation controller.

Comment: @Elgert i edited the code please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand your question completely, u want t launch a view controller from collection view cell, as a root view controller in that u can push and pop of other view controller

u can do like this,

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   LoginViewController *loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];
   UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginController]; //add this as a root view controller
   [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

**EDIT**
define a custom delegate in your custom cell for example i took an example
`CustomCollectionVIewCell` as my custom cell in `CustomCollectionVIewCell.h` i defined a custom delegate as below

```
 CustomCollectionVIewCell.h

 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 @protocol CellFooterDelegate <NSObject>
  - (void)cellFooterViewTapped; //this this is the custom delegate method
 @end

 @interface CustomCollectionVIewCell : UICollectionViewCell
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *footerCellView;
 @property (nonatomic, assign) id<CellFooterDelegate> myCustomdelegate;//define a delegate
 @end
```

in `CustomCollectionVIewCell.m`

in this method u are getting the call to this method

```
 - (void)profileTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
  {
    //some code
    if([_myCustomdelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cellFooterViewTapped)])
    {
       [_myCustomdelegate cellFooterViewTapped]; //call the delegate method 
    }

    NSLog(@"PROFILI %li",(long)gesture.view.tag);
  }
```

in the view controller where u are using the collection view u do something like this
in  confirmas to custom delegate like other delegates
    `ViewController.h`

```
#import "CustomCollectionVIewCell.h" //import the file
@interface ViewController :  UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,CellFooterDelegate>//hear i am confirming to custom delegate 
//.... other code
```

in `ViewController.m` file

```
 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {   
     CustomCollectionVIewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
     cell.myCustomdelegate = self; //important as u set self call back to this as u tap the cells footer view

     //....other code
     return cell;

 }

 //if delegate is set correctly u are getting call to this method
 - (void)cellFooterViewTapped
 {
    //hear u can push the controller
    NSLog(@"push hear");

 }
```

rest of the code as it is no need to change,

hope this helps u .. :)

**END EDIT**

Comment: this a good idea but doesnt work. I can't use `self` because I'm not calling from a class that inherits ViewController, so I need a way to get my current NavigationController and push over it

Comment: sorry now i got u are using collection view cell to present view controller rite ,show the code of entire `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: put a custom delegate from cell to view controller and push the view controller

Comment: first time i heard of custom delegate, any link where I might consult ?

Comment: hear is the link http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/

Comment: where do you live ? I want to kiss you :p

Comment: ohh thats great ..  i am  happy t help ... :) more important to know how to create custom delegates .. like above example .. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57751/discussion-between-shan-and-elgert).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method of your collection view.Its like table view didselectrow here you will get navigation controller of the view controller you can access it by self.

**Edit**

If you have used some other structure and you need to pass controll use delegate or use block to achieve it.

```
@property(nonatomic,copy)void(^cellSelect)(NSIndexPath*);
```

set your block and call it 
 in the above mentioned method

```
self.cellSelect(indexPath);
```

now you will get call in block when you select item use it to push

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention (still haven't drank coffee), I already have implemented that, It is just i want to open different view controller for different parts of the cell, and know i want to launch something from the footer, which i can only access inside the Custom CollectionViewCell method

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24825480/1008736). If you implement that, you can access the current view controller by doing:

```
[UIViewController currentViewController];
```

Comment: nice recursive function but I get an error at `findBestViewController` it doesnt recognize it, any idea ?