# Listen to NSNotification from one global place

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

In my application I need that each controller showed popup when some event happens.

I can listen to this NSNotification in each controller. But I don't want to duplicate the code.

Is there a way to listen to NSNotification and do some actions globally?

Comment: Maybe define a class that does the job and you pass the notification as a parameter and expect a result?

Comment: How does the user interact with the popup?  Is it just informational?

Comment: @Avi Popup should be able to open another view if user click OK.

Comment: @AlejandroIván good idea, but then when whenever I add new controller I have to add the code to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom UIViewController that listens to notifications, and then make all other UIViewControllers subclass it. That way they all can listen, and you do not duplicate code. I think this should work:

```
class ListeningViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("derp"), name: "herp", object: nil)
    }

    func derp() {
        print("herp-derp")
    }
}

class FunctionalViewController: ListeningViewController {
    override func derp() {
        print("i can also derp")
    }
}
```

or you can write a UIViewController extension:

```
extension UIViewController {
    public func startListenintToNotifications() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("derp"), name: "herp", object: nil)
    }

    func derp() {
        print("herp-derp")
    }
}
```

And just call the startListeningToNotificationsMethod once in every ViewController

Comment: I was also thinking about making a subclass of UIViewController. But if my controller already is a subclass of another third party controller class then it wouldn't work as I understand.

Comment: The extension looks better to me for two reasons : 1. You still get to decide which VC will be listening to this notification (there may come a time when you will not want to use it. 2. What OP said in previous comment :)

Comment: Yes, it all depends on the app architecture :) In this case, i also think that an extension would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you listen the notification in your `AppDelegate`.

Once you have catch the notification, present the popup on the **top most** view controller.

You can determine the top most view controller as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825123/get-the-current-view-controller-from-the-app-delegate).

Or just use another third-party helper: [PPTopMostController](https://github.com/ipodishima/PPTopMostController).

The following example uses [PPTopMostController](https://github.com/ipodishima/PPTopMostController) to determine the top most view controller:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NotificationName
                                                      object:nil
                                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification) {
                                                      UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Good News"
                                                                                                                     message:@"Your friend Ostap Maliuvanchuk sent you a gift!"
                                                                                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                                                      [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                                style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                                                              handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                                                                  // show the user the gift
                                                                                                  // maybe open a new controller
                                                                                              }]];

                                                      [[UIViewController topMostController] presentViewController:alert
                                                                                                         animated:YES
                                                                                                       completion:nil];
                                              }];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this.