# Swift: Determine Active View Controller when applicationDidEnterBackground is called

Tags: swift

Is there a way for me to determine the ViewController that was active when a user hits the Home button and the app delegate function **applicationDidEnterBackground** function is called?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825123/get-the-current-view-controller-from-the-app-delegate

Comment: I'm not very good with Objective-C, but I'll try to translate this post to Swift.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this line:

```
let vc: UIViewController = self.window!.rootViewController!
```

will give you the root view controller in Swift (assuming that you use that line in some method inside AppDelegate), but if you have containers (such as UITabBarController) -- you may need to go on that hierarchy for additional checks/inspections...