# Presenting popover view from inside reusable view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, popover, nib

I'm still very new at iOS development, so forgive any misconceptions I have. I am creating an application in Objective-C that has a common reusable view (let's call it the "Banner View") among many screens (call these Main Screens). In this Banner View is a button that is suppose to display a popup help display (call it the "Help View"). I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this so that I can reuse as many views as possible.

What I've tried:

1. Create two custom nibs (one for Banner View, one for Help View). This worked for displaying the Banner View across all of the Main Screens (with a UIView -> Custom Class: Banner View), but I could not figure out how to dynamically present the Help View within the Main Screens that contained Banner View.
2. Create a Banner Storyboard with both Banner View and Help View. I created corresponding Banner Controller (Initial controller in the storyboard) and Help Controller (linked with a popover segue) that I transferred the views to. Then I tried to put a container view inside my Main Screens and set the view controller custom class to Banner Controller. This didn't display the Banner at all.

What is the best way to do this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to instead put both views inside a stack view, and hide/show the Help View.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the topmost viewcontroller from your Banner View. And then present your Help screen (Help screen should be UIViewController not UIView). 
To get the top view controller you can use code form this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24825480/2984553. After that you can present your Help View with this code:

[topViewController presentViewController:HelpViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Interesting implementation, I'll check this out too. Thanks!