# How do you check current view controller class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

As far as I know, this would work in Objective-C:

```
self.window.rootViewController.class == myViewController
```

How can I check if the current view controller is a specific one?

Comment: Are you trying to determine if it's an instance of a particular class, or a specific instance?

Answer (score 98):

To check the class in Swift, use ["is" (as explained under "checking Type" in the chapter called Type Casting in the Swift Programming Guide)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338)

```
if self.window.rootViewController is MyViewController {
    //do something if it's an instance of that class
}
```

Comment: The variable `self.window` does not exist

Comment: @user83039 What is `self` in this case then? Where are you putting the code? self.window and rootViewController are in AppDelegate. Need more info.

Comment: I'm inside of a view controller.

Comment: That's the problem then - viewControllers don't have a window, and any code you put there will only tell you about itself, which isn't helpful. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485585/get-current-view-controller-from-the-app-delegate-modal-is-possible AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637709/get-the-current-displaying-uiviewcontroller-on-the-screen-in-appdelegate-m

Answer (score 50):

Updated for swift3 compiler throwing a fit around ! and ?

```
if let wd = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window {
        var vc = wd!.rootViewController
        if(vc is UINavigationController){
            vc = (vc as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController

        }

        if(vc is LogInViewController){
            //your code
        }
    }
```

Comment: No such thing as self.window

Comment: are you in AppDelegate? if not, you can get your AppDelegate and do something like that.

Comment: Awesome, this worked for me.  Just instead of `self.window` use `self.view.window`

Answer (score 32):

You can easily iterate over your view controllers if you are using a navigation controller. And then you can check for the particular instance as:
**Swift 5**

```
 if let viewControllers = navigationController?.viewControllers {
            for viewController in viewControllers {
                if viewController.isKind(of: LoginViewController.self) {
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't have an object, the current window is supposed to be the object.

Comment: Use self.isKindOfClass then

Comment: self is not necessarily what is being shown if I'm using that function from another class...

Comment: I'm using both actually. The navigation controllers are inside the tab bar controller.

Comment: What if I put this inside of a `struct` inside of the class?

Comment: Sure, you can define this inside a method of struct.

Comment: Interesting, because when I have it there, it doesn't throw errors but when I move it over, it says `'ThisViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'navigationController'` but before I moved it into the struct, it did.

Comment: I was using protocols and the delegate pattern to call common methods in one view controller class from other view controller classes and encountering the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` because those methods included statements that used storyboard outlets only attached to the specific view controller associated with the class containing the methods but not the other classes (i.e. `self.myButton.hidden = true` where myButton is an IBOutlet connected to just one view controller). I used your template as a wrapper for these statements. Thank you

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
if self is MyViewController {        

}
```

Comment: self is not necessarily what is being shown if I'm using a function from another class...

Comment: Thanks, this helped. This is particularly useful for checking the currently presenting viewController. I was able to tell whether the controller was a UIAlertController to prevent multiple presentations.

Answer (score 13):

I had to find the current viewController in AppDelegate.
I used this

```
//at top of class
var window:UIWindow?

// inside my method/function
if let viewControllers = window?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers {
    for viewController in viewControllers {
        if viewController.isKindOfClass(MyViewControllerClass) {
            println("Found it!!!")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3**

Not sure about you guys, but I'm having a hard time with this one. I did something like this:

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window {
    if var viewController = window?.rootViewController {
        // handle navigation controllers
        if(viewController is UINavigationController){
            viewController = (viewController as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController!
        }
        print(viewController)
    }
}
```

I kept getting the initial view controller of my app. For some reason it wanted to stay the root view controller no matter what. So I just made a global string type variable `currentViewController` and set its value myself in each `viewDidLoad()`. All I needed was to tell which screen I was on & this works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 7):

To go off of Thapa's answer, you need to cast to the viewcontroller class before using...

> ```
>    if let wd = self.view.window {
>         var vc = wd.rootViewController!
>         if(vc is UINavigationController){
>             vc = (vc as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController
>         }
>         if(vc is customViewController){
>             var viewController : customViewController = vc as! customViewController
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4, Swift 5

```
let viewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
if viewController is MyViewController {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For types you can use `is` and if it is your own viewcontroller class then you need to use `isKindOfClass` like:

```
let vcOnTop = self.embeddedNav.viewControllers[self.embeddedNav.viewControllers.count-1]
            if vcOnTop.isKindOfClass(VcShowDirections){
                return
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 | Check if a view controller is the root from within itself.**

You can access `window` from within a view controller, you just need to use `self.view.window`.

Context: I need to update the position of a view and trigger an animation when the device is rotated. I only want to do this if the view controller is active.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self, 
            selector: #selector(deviceDidRotate), 
            name: .UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientation, 
            object: nil
        )
    }

    func deviceDidRotate() {
        guard let window = self.view.window else { return }

        // check if self is root view controller
        if window.rootViewController == self {
            print("vc is self")
        }

        // check if root view controller is instance of MyViewController
        if window.rootViewController is MyViewController {
            print("vc is MyViewController")
        }
    }
}
```

If you rotate your device while MyViewController is active, you will see the above lines print to the console. If MyViewController is not active, you will not see them.

If you're curious why I'm using `UIDeviceOrientationDidChange` instead of `.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange`, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42863379/4754881).

Answer (score 1):

```
let viewControllers = navController?.viewControllers
        for aViewController in viewControllers! {

            if aViewController .isKind(of: (MyClass?.classForCoder)!) {
                _ = navController?.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that way that worked better for me [What is .self](https://swiftrocks.com/whats-type-and-self-swift-metatypes.html)

```
if ((self.window.rootViewController?.isKind(of: WebViewController.self))!)
{
  //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**After implementing and try is current viewController is open I find 100% solution**

for example **when receiving a new notification**

here the implement using 'userNotificationCenter'

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    
    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    
    let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
        .compactMap({$0})
        .first?.windows
        .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
    
    guard let window = keyWindow else { return }
    
    if window.rootViewController?.children.last is MyViewController{
        print("Chat")
        completionHandler([])
    }else{
        print("Not not not Chat")
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
 }
```

**and simply to check try this**

```
let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
        .compactMap({$0})
        .first?.windows
        .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
    
    guard let window = keyWindow else { return }
    
    if window.rootViewController?.children.last is MyViewController{
        print("Yes Its current ViewController")
    }else{
        print("Not it's not Current ViewController")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5 and iOS 15**

```
if self.navigationController?.presentedViewController != nil && 
        self.navigationController?.presentedViewController is ChatViewController {
            return
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let index = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.index(where: { $0 is MyViewController }) {
            let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[vcIndex] as! MyViewController
            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
        } else {
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is a variation on Kiran's answer above. I used this in a project.

**Swift 5**

```
// convenience property API on my class object to provide access to the my WindowController (MyController).
var myXWindowController: MyController? {

    var myWC: MyController?                
    for viewController in self.windowControllers {
        if ((viewController as? MyController) != nil) {
            myWC = viewController as? MyController
            break
        }
    }

    return myWC
}

// example of use
guard let myController = myXWindowController else {
    reportAssertionFailure("Failed to get MyXController from WindowController.")
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var top = window?.rootViewController
            while ((top?.presentedViewController) != nil) {
                top = top?.presentedViewController
            }
            
            if !(type(of: top!) === CallingVC.self) {
                top?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "CallingVC", sender: call)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I chose to create my own enum to keep track of which view controller I was on:

```swift
enum currentViewController{
   case publicVC
   case homeVC
   case friendsVC
}
```

Then in each of your `viewWillAppear`s change a global variable to equal the respective enum.