# How to add an image in between the texts in a alert view?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I have an alert view in which i need to display a icon in between the texts of the alert view as like in the image below. This alert comes after uploading a video file to server in my app asynchronously. Any suggestions how to do it.

I am using Swift 2.2 xcode 7.3

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7 Check this post

Comment: Have a look at `NSAttributedString` and `NSTextAttachment` and then combine them with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color

Comment: @Fogmeister Thanks for the hint. I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by creating a custom view controller where i placed a `UIView` at the centre with the dimensions similar to the alert box and set its constraints to `centre horizontally`, `centre vertically` , `fixed width` and `fixed height`. Inside i place a `label` with the text and the long space in between the place where the image has to be. then i place a `image view` with the image correctly in this gap.
The view's corner radius is set to `13px` and background color to match the alert box style.

Then as @Sushree's answer suggested, set the presentation style. But setting it programmatically didn't work for me. But setting it in the `StoryBoard` works for all IOS versions (8.0 to 9.3) as i checked.

Select `UIViewController`->`Attributes inspector`->`Presentation`->`Over Current Context`

I am using a `UINavigationController` as the `RootViewController` so i used the following code

```
if let wd = appDelegate.window {
                var vc = wd.rootViewController
                if(vc is UINavigationController){
                    vc = (vc as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController
                    vc!.presentViewController(PopupViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
                }
            }
```

Reference [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715861/how-do-you-check-current-view-controller-class-in-swift)

Answer (score 2):

If this image is an emoji or a unicode character you can add it directly in your text in a `UIAlertViewController` . Do NOT use `UIAlertView` since it has been deprecated.

However for better customizability I would recommend creating a custom view and adding it to your VC with a background overlay when it has to be shown

If you wish to create the custom alert, there are several open source examples here

[Open source Custom Alerts](http://www.code4app.net/category/alertview)

and If you would like to use a `UIAlertController` , this link has great examples

[UIAlertController examples](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8/)

Comment: no this is not a unicode character. I have this image in my assets.Could you share a code snippet on how to show a `UIalertViewController` or `CustomView` to show like a alert when a background process is completed.

Comment: Also for the background process, you should have some kind of completion closure that is called

Comment: Yes in the completion closure i am showing this alert disregarding the Viewcontroller in which the user is currently viewing

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a custom View and use it as your alert ?

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let myAlert = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("alert")
myAlert.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
myAlert.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

There you can do anything you like.

As far as emojis are related you can add them from :-

```
Xcode Edit ->  Emoji & Symbols
```

There are a lot of them to select from !!!

Comment: thanks for your hint. But that image is not in the emoji table. It is a custom image from my assets.

Comment: @KauthamMurugan then u can try my first option

Comment: But the problem is this alert is triggered at the completion block of the background upload process which i wrote in a global class. So i don't know in which ViewController the user will be in.

Answer (score 0):

From [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) of Apple, you could  use unicode scalars which you would like to use.

> Unicode Scalars
>
> Behind the scenes, Swift’s native String type is built from Unicode
>   scalar values. A Unicode scalar is a unique 21-bit number for a
>   character or modifier, such as U+0061 for LATIN SMALL LETTER A ("a"),
>   or U+1F425 for FRONT-FACING BABY CHICK ("").

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28907826/1887603) can also be helpful.