# How to use a variable in other class that is defined in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I have a variable `var window: UIWindow?` in AppDelegate.swift file inside `class AppDelegate` that I want to use in other class xyz.swift file inside `class xyz` as explained in here [Get current view controller from the app delegate (modal is possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485585/get-current-view-controller-from-the-app-delegate-modal-is-possible) but I am getting error at the first line any help will be appreciated. here is the code from xyz.swift

```
func CurrentView() -> UIView
  {
     let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController // Use of Unresolved identifier 'window'
     if let activeController = navigationController!.visibleViewController {
     if activeController.isKindOfClass( MyViewController )  {
       println("I have found my controller!")
          }
      }
  }
```

Even if I use `let navigationController = AppDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController` error is  `'AppDelegate.Type' does not have member named 'window'`

Comment: Where have you defined var windows? Is it in AppDelegate class or just inside the file? Also where is CurrentView() method is defined? Please post code with context.

Comment: `var window: UIWindow?` is in AppDelegate class and `CurrentView()` function is another class named `class ServiceManager: NSObject {` what else code you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to do as follows:

```
    var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let navigationController = appDelegate.window?....
```

As @Dave Durbin has pointed out you are trying to use a variable defined in one class into another class without the reference of the defining class.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code is in `xyz.swift`

```
  let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController // Use of Unresolved identifier 'window'
```

You don't provide any context for `window` so it's expected to be in this class or a global variable.

This is closer:

```
navigationController = AppDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
```

and you seem to realise that you need to reference the window variable within your AppDelegate instance however the syntax you are using references a static variable and window is a member variable.

I suggest you read through the swift manual and gain a better understanding of variable scopes and check this:

[How do I get a reference to the app delegate in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046164/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-the-app-delegate-in-swift)